# Designing for an Android handset and testing on a tablet

Tags: android

I'm looking to get back into Android development as a hobby, and I'd like to have a device to use for testing. Seeing as the only Android handset I currently own is the original Motorola DROID, however, I'd like to get something a little less... *dated*.

Buying a new Android handset on a plan with a carrier is an option, as is a used handset. However, I've seen a lot of much cheaper Android tablets that make that route far more appealing from a financial standpoint.

Developing for iOS lets you use an iPad as a test platform for your app that's optimized for a phone, and you have the option to either run in a windowed mode at the resolution your app is optimized for or to run it in a magnified 2X mode.

How does Android handle this kind of thing? Do you design a single app and the interface scales itself in some fashion? Or, as in the default iOS behavior, will it center itself at the resolution that your app is optimized for?

Answer (score 1):

You could skip relying on devices, use Chrome, and change your User Agent. You can even target specific iOS and Android versions 'User Agent', as well as setting the windows resolution 'Device Metrics'

Right click a window, inspect element, sprocket at bottom right, 'Overrides'.

Comment: Fair enough, though this wouldn't give the same experience from an interaction standpoint. But it _is_ food for thought, thank you!

Comment: Certainly! Save some money, and make accessibility for you easier in the process too.

Comment: This will only work for Web development, or phonegap-style "canned" web-app projects, not for generic development of Java-coded apps.

Answer (score 0):

No, to date there's no standard mechanism for an Android device to simulate a different size device.

However, most apps will want to work on a range of devices anyway.  You may find it expeditious to do 90% of your work on whatever available device is fastest at installing and running builds while moving the development forward, and then less frequently use a variety of other devices and/or emulators to test for compatibility with other sizes, dpis, Android versions, etc.